# Prove using the integral test that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{2+e^n}$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

I have to prove using the integral test that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{2+e^n}$ converges.

I already showed that $f(x)=\frac{2}{2+e^x}$ is continuos, positive and is decreasing in $[1,\infty)$.

I'm struggling with the integral $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{2+e^x} \,dx$

$$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{2+e^x} \,dx$$
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{1}^{t} \frac{2}{2+e^x} \,dx$$
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}2\int_{1}^{t} \frac{1}{2+e^x} \,dx$$

By substitution I get:

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}2\int_{e}^{e^t} \frac{1}{u(2+u)} \,du$$

By partial fractions I get:

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}2\int_{e}^{e^t} [\frac{1}{2u}-\frac{1}{2(2+u)}] \,du$$

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}2\cdot\frac{1}{2}\int_{e}^{e^t} [\frac{1}{u}-\frac{1}{2+u}] \,du$$

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{e}^{e^t} [\frac{1}{u}-\frac{1}{2+u}] \,du$$

After solving:

$$\lim_{t\to\infty} [(\ln|e^t|-\ln|e|)-(\ln|2+e^t|-\ln|2+e|)]$$

$$\lim_{t\to\infty} [(\ln(e^t)-1-\ln(2+e^t)+\ln(2+e)]$$

$$\lim_{t\to\infty} [(\ln(e^t)-\ln(2+e^t)-1+\ln(2+e)]$$

$$\lim_{t\to\infty} [\ln\frac{e^t}{2+e^t}-1+\ln(2+e)]$$

I'm getting $\ln(1)=0$ in $\lim_{t\to\infty} [\ln\frac{e^t}{2+e^t}]$ using L'Hopital.

So at the end,

$$=-1+\ln(2+e)$$

So because the integral converges, then the series converges.

The thing is that when I put $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{2+e^x} \,dx$ in [www.symbolab.com](http://www.symbolab.com) it says that diverges. In [www.emathhelp.net](http://www.emathhelp.net) the result is $-4+4\ln(2+e)$

So I'm in so much doubt now.

Comment: You should note that $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{2+e^{x}}dx \leq \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{e^{x}}dx <\infty$

Comment: Yes, Symbolab has an incorrect antiderivative and hence concludes incorrectly.  Your analysis is fine.

Comment: @MarkViola so is the process correct? Because www.emathhelp.com gives me another result. :-S

Comment: @EvanWilliamChandra for what do I need that information?

Comment: I believe that your answer is correct.