# Denote $s=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{2+e^n}$ and $s_N=\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{2}{2+e^n}$ with $N=1,2,\ldots$ Find $N$ such that $|s-s_n|<10^{-6}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Denote $s=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{2+e^n}$ and $s_N=\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{2}{2+e^n}$ with $N=1,2,\ldots$ Find $N$ such that $|s-s_n|<10^{-6}$

The first part of this exercise was to prove using the integral test that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{2+e^n}$ converges. I did this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4197904/prove-using-the-integral-test-that-sum-n-1-infty-frac22en-converge?noredirect=1#comment8708629_4197904).

Now I have this:

$$|s-s_n|<10^{-6}$$

$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{2+e^n}-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{2}{2+e^n} \right| <10^{-6}$$

Then I don't know what to do if I have to substitute the result of the sum I get [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4197904/prove-using-the-integral-test-that-sum-n-1-infty-frac22en-converge?noredirect=1#comment8708629_4197904) in $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{2+e^n}$. If so, what do I do with $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{2}{2+e^n}$? Give values to the $N$ till I get that the absolute value of the difference of them is less than $10^{-6}$

Comment: Saying "Find $N$ such that $|s-s_n|<10^{-6}$" doesn't make much sense, because there's no $N$ in the conclusion $|s-s_n|<10^{-6}$

Comment: I'm surprised that an integral test was proposed, since it seems simpler to just say $0<\dfrac 2{2+e^n}<\dfrac 2{e^n}$ and $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 2 {e^n}$ is a convergent geometric series.

Comment: You must have meant "Find $N$ such that for all $n\ge N,$ $|s-s_n|<10^{-6}. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I thought the same that by Direct Comparison Test I could show that it converges but I think that Integral Test was proposed to evaluate our knowledge on it. For the premise, I wrote it exactly as I saw it.  What do I do with $|s-s_n|<10^{-6}$?

Answer (score 1):

$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{2+e^n}-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{2}{2+e^n} \right| \\ = \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{2+e^n}\\ < 2\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}e^{-n}\\ = \frac{2e^{-(N+1)}}{1-e^{-1}}\\ \lt e^{-(N+1)}\\ =(e^3)^{-(N+1)/3}\\ \lt 10^{-(N+1)/3} $$
So $N=17$ suffices. However, this is by no means the smallest value of such an $N$.

Comment: (+1) nice approach !

Comment: @Med-Elf :) ${}$

Answer (score 0):

You must have meant "Find $N$ such that for all $n\ge N,$ $|s-s_n|< 10^{-6}.$ I will assume that that is what was intended.

\begin{align}
& |s-s_n| = \left| \sum_{m\,=\,n+1}^\infty \frac 2 {2+e^m} \right| \\[8pt]
\le {} & \sum_{m\,=\,n+1}^\infty \frac 1 {e^m} = \frac 1 {e^n(e-1)}
\end{align}
And $e^n(e-1)>10^6$ if $n>\log\left( 10^6/(e-1)\right).$